# Data tables header width/alignment issue

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, datatables, css

I am having a problem with the data tables jquery plugin where my headers are not aligning properly with the table. I noticed that if I add cellspacing=0 to the table it will align correctly. However, this attribute isn't supposed in HTML5 and I would like this to work in HTML5 as well if possible. If you look at the dotted border lines, the header ones do to match the content table lines.

Here is the javascript I am using to create the table.

```
myTableHere = $('#MyTableHere').dataTable({
    'sScrollY': '100px',
    'bPaginate': false,
    'bScrollCollapse': true,
    'bFilter': false,
    'bInfo': false,
    'bSort': false,
    "aoColumns": [
        { "sWidth": "95px" },
        { "sWidth": "267px" },
        { "sWidth": "77px" },
        { "sWidth": "90px" },
        { "sWidth": "90px" },
        { "sWidth": "42px" }
    ]
});
```

This is being viewed in the latest version of chrome.
[image]

Here is some sample HTML before I data tablefy it. https://gist.github.com/anonymous/d44360d3a06c1a5b2898

**Edit: I found that by adding border collapse to the header table, it solved the issue.**

Comment: Can you add some sample HTML of your table (with headers and some actual rows)?

Comment: HTML pre "datatabled" or post "datatabled"

Comment: pre -- what are you starting with.

Comment: I believe I see a scrollbar for the table body. I wonder if that factors in. Also, to facilitate the scrollbar, is the "header" actually a separate table from the table itself (whether by your code explicitly or as an "automagic" feature of the API)? Even when specified as pixel values, column widths are always subject to adjustment by the browser, so it's kind of a craps shoot putting tables on top of one-another and hoping they'll line up.

Comment: @GregPettit The header is indeed in a separate table than the contents table. The Data Tables plugin automagically splits the header into a different table above it so that the contents can scroll independently.

Comment: @JacobM I have added a sample

Comment: Justin, that's what I was afraid of. Particularly with that scrollbar, it's going to be difficult to get the two to align. I tried getting this done the other day for another question, and I threw in the towel (couldn't spend more of my employer's time)... the way browsers use column widths as a "guideline" proved to be difficult to overcome. Someone out there knows the secret, but it isn't me!

Comment: After having initialized your datatable try adding : myTableHere.fnSort([[0, 'asc']]); . In my case, a reordering of my datatable align header table with the content's one

Comment: I found that by adding border collapse to the header table, it solved the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the table that I was using the data tables plugin on, I had a the `border-collapse: collapse;` css property applied to it. This property was still being applied to the content table after the plugin had finished tablfying my table. However, the seperate header table did not have this css property applied to it as well. After setting the header table to also be border collapse, the lines lined up properly.